# Export sp_help 'table' to file in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, bcp, sp-help-operator

I would like to know how I can export the result of `sp_help 'table'` to a `.txt` file.

When we run `sp_help` from a table, it returns various results that I would like to be saved to a file.

This is an example of what I want to save

```
EXEC sp_help 'dbo.masVBS'
```

[image]

I tried to use bcp but it only exports me the first result.

```
DECLARE @OutputFilePath nvarchar(max); SET @OutputFilePath = 'L:\ObsoleteObjects\'

DECLARE @ExportSQL nvarchar(max); SET @ExportSQL = N'EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell ''bcp "use ehs exec sp_help ''''dbo.masVBS''''" queryout "' + @OutputFilePath + '\OutputData.txt" -T -c -t -S'''

EXEC(@ExportSQL)
```

Is there a solution to export this result in a single file?

Comment: Creating a single file it would be hard to read as headers would be different (inline).  You could use SSIS to loop through the result sets (that is what each grouping of data is) and save each one to their own files.  Or if you wanted to you could save all to 1 file with C# script task in SSIS).

Comment: This behaviour is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver16): *"If the query returns multiple result sets, only the first result set is copied to the data file; **subsequent result sets are ignored**."* `bcp` is *not* the tool you want here. Even more so when cludged together with `xp_cmdshell`. Use Powershell, Python, C#, or something that's much better equipped.

Comment: Also why are you going to to shell using `xp_cmdshell` only to call back in using `bcp`. Why not just open a command prompt and execute `bcp.exe`?